# why is erythrocyte sedimentation rate higher in females?

Tags: hematology, blood-circulation

erythocyte sedimentation rate should be independent of the sex.
what is the reason behind this sex bias and why does it increase during pregnancy and how does age influence it.

Comment: Why would you think ESR should be independent of sex? Do you understand what the test is and what it indicates? What have you done to try to find out why it's not independent of sex?